# can anyone see why this wont post to wall?

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

i had my things all working until i started peronalising the look of it, and now when i try to post something to a wall, it wont post, but it was before i changed my button.

this is my post page with my if statement

```
$status2 = $_POST['status2'];

$uid = $facebook->getUser();

$args = array(
    'message'   => $_POST['status2'],
    'link'      => 'http://apps.facebook.com/geordie-status/',
    'caption'   => 'Translate from English to Geordie'
);

if(isset($_POST['post']))

{

$post_id = $facebook->api("/$uid/feed", "post", $args);
header( "Refresh: 5; url=index.php");
}

?>
```

obviolsy the problem lies with that statement somwhere because it wont post and it wont redirect.

my page that leads to my post.php

```
<div align="center">
<form method="POST" action="post.php" >
<textarea name="status2" cols="50" rows="5"/>
<?php echo str_ireplace(array ('old','awkward','all','again','behind','along','alright','hello','among','children','yes','child','kids','food','barnard castle','beer','book','blow','beautiful','bird','burst','brown','burn','boots'), 
array ('auld', 'aakwad', 'aall','agyen','ahint','alang','alreet','alreet','amang','bairns','aye','bairn','bairns','bait','barney','beor','beuk','blaa','bonny','bord','borst','broon','bourn','byeuts'),$status); ?> 

</textarea><br>
<input type="image" name="post" src="images/posttowall.png" />
</form>

</div>
```

i cant help but feel that the issue lies with the button name, but when i change it to 'submit' for example, it still gives the same issue.

I hope someone can help

Comment: its probably worth mentioning, that when i do change the button name, i also change it in the if statement on post.php

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a copy of the code before your changes at the point where it was working, would you?

Comment: sorry, ive already figured a way around it. i just changed my button back to 'submit' and then changed the css, works again now :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a section that perfoms authorization to the facebook graph API.
Just add this to the top of the code.

```
<?php
include_once("facebook.php"); 
$app_id = "*****YOUR_APP_ID*****";
$app_secret = "*******YOUR_APP_SECRET*********";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $app_secret
 ));

$uid = $facebook->getUser();
```

Comment: i already have that at the top, but didnt include in the paste as i felt it would add nothing in terms of a solution

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox, it won't send the name `post` in the POST data, but `post.x` and `post.y`.
This is because you used an image as the submit button of the form, and Firefox sends the `x` and `y` coordinates of the point you clicked relative to the top left corner of the image.